# Windows Forms - ToolStripItem Visible property is always set to false

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripdropdown

I'm working on a `MDI Windows Forms` application. My parent form has `ToolStrip` menu and some `ToolStripDropDownButtons`. I want to change the `Visible` property of the `ToolStripDropDownButton` or to some of the `ToolStripItems` (sub buttons) that it has accordingly to the permission of the user.

Here is the part of the method that I've wrote to manage this:

```
private void SetToolStripDropDownVisibility(ToolStripDropDownButton mainBtn, params ToolStripItem[] item)
{
     mainBtn.Visible = false;
     foreach (ToolStripItem tempItem in item)
     {
         tempItem.Visible = true;
     }
}
```

I'm passing as first argument the `ToolStripDropDownButton` and all other "sub buttons" as params list. However when I get into debug mode in the part `foreach (ToolStripItem tempItem in item)` the `tempItem` Visible property is marked as false. In the designer however this property is set to true. You can see that I even try explicitly to change the value to true - `tempItem.Visible = true;` but it seems as if this line is doing nothing. The value of `Visible` remains `false` and I can't change it.

This is just the begining of the method and I can't think of other code that can mess up with the `ToolStrip` items. I tried to change the value of `mainBtn.Visible` to true or false thinking that maybe there's any connection but it seems this is not the issues. So any idea why this is happening, why I cant change the `Visible` value and of course any way to do it.

Comment: changing "item" to "items" does not harm, and will improve the readability much.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The solution is easy and yet not obvious. When we have to work with `ToolStripItems` which are part of `ToolSTripDropDownButton` and solve visibility problem the way we used to solve it with ordinary buttons we have to use `Available` property. It is designed exactly for this purpose. Hope someone gonna spend less time dealing with this problem by reading this!

Comment: That's not how it works.  Available and Visible are *almost* identical properties and setting one changes the other.  But with one difference, the Visible property only returns true when the user can see the item.  Which will never be the case inside your form constructor or Load event, the form isn't yet visible.  So high odds that there was not a real problem to being with, you just got confused by what the debugger told you.

Comment: The problem was how in runtime to determine what is visible and what not for certain user due to his permissions. If any `ToolStripItem` is available then the `DropDownButton` should be visible if there is no `ToolStripItem` available for the user the `DropDownButton` should be hidden too. Using `Visible` property doesn't help here, because as you said it will always return false and my `DropDownButton` will always be hidden. But if I set the `Available` property then everything is ok.

Answer (score 1):

The following will go trough all `toolstripitems` within `menuStrip1`:

```
           List<ToolStripMenuItem> allItems = new List<ToolStripMenuItem>();
            foreach (ToolStripMenuItem toolItem in menuStrip1.Items) 
            {
                allItems.Add(toolItem);
                //add sub items
                allItems.AddRange(GetItems(toolItem));
            }
            foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in allItems)
            {
                //make your toolstripMenuItem invisible or whatever you want to do with it.
            }
            allItems.Clear();
```

Change `menuStrip1` to whatever you call your `toolstrip`.

Comment: The problem is not that I can't make a list of my `ToolStrip` items I want the problem is that they have `Visible` set to false and I can't find a way to change it to true. `item.Visible = true` leaves the item invisible and in debug mode the value of visible after this row is still false even though I just have set it to true.