# Hide some menu from MenuStrip Winfoms

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

I have a MenuStrip in my Windows Form Application which Contains MenuItems.

I want to check some condition and disable the visibility of MenuItems in the MenuStrip bar. 
Suppose Normal User is accessing the application ,then Some MenuItems will be hidden and if Admin user is accessing the application then all MenuItems should be visible.

This is my code (I'am not sure about it ) which didn't work.

```
  public Visite(string username)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = username;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=timar;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            con.Open();
            bool UserIsAdmin = true;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [User] where Role =@Role", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", "Admin");

                UserIsAdmin = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
            }
            if (UserIsAdmin == false)
            {
                utilisateurToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
            }
           else
           {
               utilisateurToolStripMenuItem.Visible= true;
            }
           con.Close();
       }

    }
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set  utilisateurToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false and not enabled, Enabled will still show you menu

Comment: I think you should enable readonly

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about visibility in your question, but your Code says Enabled.

These are two completely different things.

In case you stick with visbility the you should set `utilisateurToolStripMenuItem.Visible` to false

Answer (score 0):

try This..

```
public Visite(string username)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    label1.Text = username;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=timar;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        con.Open();
        bool UserIsAdmin = false;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [User] where Role =@Role", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", "Admin");
            UserIsAdmin = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
        }
       utilisateurToolStripMenuItem.Visible = UserIsAdmin;
     }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work , `utilisateurToolStripMenuItem` still always Visible for all Type of Users

Comment: @Yosra, Debug and see what is value the of "UserIsAdmin" being returned from database.

Comment: The value of `UserIsAdmin` is TRUE

Comment: is this value is TRUE for Normal User also ?

Comment: Yes , for normal User also

Comment: which is wrong, this should be FALSE for normal user. That is the reason, It is always visible, change the value in Database and then run the code, your menu will be hidden

Comment: You are getting confused by what debugger is telilng you. See this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15742499/547239

Comment: I see the link above and change VISIBLE by AVAILABLE , there is no difference  problem  persist again
The problem in the line `UserIsAdmin = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0` , The value of  `UserIsAdmin` is True (which should be FALSE)